# Displaying 2nd Window Issue

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am dealing with 2 windows . One is created by Qt Designer and i import it
on test.py program . what i did i make a Widget on the test program and
than add a button to it and on click event I try to popup the other
window(gui1.py) created by Qt Designer but it never pop ups  and when i use
break and do line by line debugging it shows me this message after running
this command "myapp2 = MyForm()" on line number 35 test.py .

QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running

and once i pressed enter on the terminal it pop up the other window .

I am confuse where i am wrong .

Thanks
[test.py](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg26206/test.py)
[gui1.py](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg26206/gui1.py)

Comment: Your question has been answered, but in future could you please avoid cross-posting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the other window doesn't appear, is because you are not keeping a reference to it, and so it gets garbage-collected immediately after it is shown.

To fix the problem, you could either store the window instance it as an attribute, or give it a parent:

```
def local_manag(self):
    print "pressed"
    # store it as an attribute
    self.myapp2 = MyForm()
    self.myapp2.show()
    # or give it a parent
    # myapp2 = MyForm(self)
    # myapp2.show()
```

Comment: @EricHulser. I was going to give you an upvote and call it a draw, but you deleted your answer too quickly :)

Comment: Thanks alot ekhumoro :) but one question why it does show me when i do line by line debugging

Comment: @user1224233. Not sure, but maybe the debugger is temporarily keeping the window alive.