# no response when click button using pyqt

Tags: pyqt, block

No response when click button(using for executing signal-slot function) using pyqt,but when I switch to command window and click 'enter',gui will continue, how to eliminate the bug?

Comment: Please refer the following question in stack overflow.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996478/displaying-2nd-window-issue

Comment: Please read the following guidelines on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question accordingly to what is said there. Add code, screenshot or any other ressource that could help us have a better understanding of your problem. I can see that you are new here in Stack Overflow, the only advice I can give you is: If you expect good answers on this site, ask good questions. I'll be glad to help you once your question will be edited.